# Flask requests not working when application is deployed

Tags: python, iis, flask, python-requests, windows-server-2016

I deployed a flask application in **Windows Server 2016** on **IIS**. Everything was working fine, then I updated windows and now, I'm unable to use *requests.get()* when deployed.

Here is a simple code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import request

import requests


app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}}, send_wildcard=True)



@app.route("/")
def hello():
    r = requests.get('http://google.com')
    return r.text


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print ("\nAttempting to start server ...")
    app.run(threaded = True, port=5052)
```

When I run it, it browser will hang for 30s or so, and then returns a 500 error.

The server has access the internet: i can browse, use pip and I'm even able to do requests from the python command line or as a stand alone program, but not when it's deployed.

I have tried headers, cors, played with pratically all possible settings. I have no idea why it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Please provide the console output. Are you getting 'Attempting to start server' this print? Also please switch on the debug and post the output here for better understanding.

Comment: That part of the code is not executed when the flask application uses wfastcgi and it's deployed. So you can ignore the "main" part.

Comment: No matter if it's python, php or any other language. All aplications works except requests in python and curl or get_file_contents in php. If I call a web service directly from the server's browser (javascript or i address bar) it works, but not from localhost or from the IIS. It almost look like the IIS is blocking these type of operations.

Answer (score 0):

can u change your protocol as https..It works fine for me..:) I too spent nearly one hour for trying out all possibilities.
Sorry for turning out this to be simple :)
Interesting this is my first solution on stack overflow..

Comment: No luck. The IIS keeps blocking any sort of connection to external web services(for example google maps api), file downloads, etc.

Comment: Problem solved. It appears that the sys adm did something and didn't say anything. What exactly, I have no idea.